# I do not know what it means by the metro file

Tags: java, android, react-native, uimanager

I do not know what it means by the metro file, nor where to find it, and how to close it and start it again. Does it mean the Android emulator or what?

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: "Project" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I closed the Android emulator and expected the problem to go away, but the result was this

```
[react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).

For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation
 LOG Running "Project" with {"rootTag":1}
 ERROR Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager

This error is located at:
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Project(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Project(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the error message `react-native-gesture-handler module was not found` right? it means you need to install it. try `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: Thank you. I followed your answer and downloaded
 npm react-native-gesture-handler and it solved the problem

Comment: If the problem solved please kindly mark the answer to close the thread, thanks